# Cosmos Client object getting disposed though registered as SingleInstance

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

When trying to  `var res = await container.ReadContainerAsync();`
I get a `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosObjectDisposedException. 'Cannot access a disposed 'CosmosClient'. Follow best practices and use the CosmosClient as a singleton`

This is how I register (via Autofac 4.6) the CosmosClient and the classes that use it - all of them as SingleInstance:

```
builder.Register<CosmosClient>(_ => new CosmosClient(myConnectionString)).SingleInstance();
    
builder.Register<Database>(_ =>
{
     var client = _.Resolve<CosmosClient>();
     return client.GetDatabase(myDbName);
}). SingleInstance();
    
builder.RegisterType<MyCosmosDbClient>()
.SingleInstance()
.AsImplementedInterfaces();
    
builder.Register<Container>(_ => _.Resolve<Database>().GetContainer(FirstContainerName))
.SingleInstance()
    .Named<Container>(FirstContainerName);
    
builder.Register<Container>(_ => _.Resolve<Database>().GetContainer(SecondConatinerName))
                                .SingleInstance()
                                .Named<Container>(SecondContainerName);

builder
 .Register(_ => new SecondContainerDataProvider(_.Resolve<ICosmosDbClient>(), 
 _.ResolveNamed<Container>(SecondContainerName))
                .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                .SingleInstance();
```

Any ideas why does it happen?